# Wireless Network not connecting to broadcasted network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have a laptop with a fresh install of Windows 7. My wireless network "Skynet" is broadcasting and is using AES encryption. The laptop can pick up the wireless network but cannot connect. I set up a network manually with the exact settings that are working on a wireless desktop. The laptop still cannot connect but when I run the diagnostic tool it says the Windows cannot connect to the hidden network "Skynet". The network is not hidden though and is clearly broadcasting on said laptop. Any ideas as to what could be going on with this?

Comment: What is the access point are you using?

Comment: You're probably going to need to take a heuristic approach to this. Can you give us more information...Like the model of access point and your results of running `ipconfig /all` from the command prompt of the computer that won't connect, and if you have them results from a computer on the network that can connect to the access point?